# The method .joins() must contain arguments (Syntax problem from Rails v4.2.1 to Rails v6.1.3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, lambda

I have been working on an App called CtrlPanel for the company I work for.
This app was originally running on Ruby v2.2.2 and rails v4.2.1.  I could not get that environment to work on ANYTHING; I tried both PC and Linux.  Since I couldn't get that environment running and since it needed to be updated to the newest version anyway I figured I would just get it working on the latest version.

I had no idea what I was in for, that was a little over a month ago.  I am happy to report I now have everything in the program working with one exception.  There is a catalog that displays all of the items and it uses a scope in the model with a lambda expression that is rather complicated (at least to me).  I have had to update the syntax ALL over this application due to the older version of Rails and now being on the newest version and this is the only one I can't seem to figure out. I am pretty sure again that it is just a Syntax problem from Rails v4.2.1 to Rails v6.1.3.1 but I just can't seem to figure it out and I am sure people who are more experienced than myself will know what it is.

Here is the model in question:

category.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_categories

  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
  has_many :product_categories, dependent: :destroy

  default_scope { order("id") }
  scope :with_published_products, -> { joins{product_categories.product}.where{products.status.eq "published"}.uniq }
  scope :with_matched_search_terms, ->(search_terms) { joins{product_categories.product}.where{products.name.like search_terms}.uniq }
end
```

The line with the issue is:
scope :with_published_products, -> { joins{product_categories.product}.where{products.status.eq "published"}.uniq }

It is giving the error:
The method .joins() must contain arguments

I had other joins statements that I had to fix (numerous). It was due to syntax for a very BASIC example from joins{arguments} to joins(arguments). I assume that is the same case here.  In this case there are many more elements and that lambda expression thrown into the mix which is making it much harder (for me at least) to get it corrected.  I have tried every version of changing that line around I can think of and probably many that do not make sense.  I have one version where it will get past the line but then when that "with_published_products" is called later in the view it errors out with a bad PG statement and when I traced it back it was due to the very same query.   Here is the view involved:

```
- if current_user
  .pull-left{style: "position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px;"}
    = link_to products_path do
      %button.btn{style: "margin-top: 0px;  "}
        %i.icon-arrow-left.icon-large
        %b back to products
.row-fluid
  .span12
    %h1.bigred DPF Product Catalog
    %hr
.row-fluid
  .span12
    - unless @categories.empty?
      .tabbable.tabbable-left
        %ul.nav.nav-tabs{style: "text-align:right;"}
          %li.active
            %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#tab-#{@categories.first.id}"} #{@categories.first.name}
          - @categories.each do |category|
            -unless category == @categories.first
              %li
                %a{"data-toggle" => "tab", :href => "#tab-#{category.id}"} #{category.name}
        .tab-content
          - @categories.each_with_index do |category, i|
            .tab-pane.fade{id: "tab-#{category.id}", class: "#{ 'in active' if i.zero? }"}
              %h1.bigred.professional{style: "text-align:left;"} #{category.name}
              %hr
                - @params_name.blank? ? @products = category.products.published.includes(:pictures).order("name asc") : @products = category.products.searched(@params_name).published.includes(:pictures).order("name asc")
                = render partial: 'product', collection: @products, cache: true
    - else
      %h2
        There were no products matching
        %b #{@params_name.gsub(/%/, '')}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  
  #skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:catalog, :roi]
  skip_before_action  :authenticate_user!, :only => [:catalog, :roi]
  
  #skip_authorization_check
  before_action

  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def catalog
    if params[:name].present?
      @params_name = "%#{params[:name]}%"
      @categories = Category.with_published_products.with_matched_search_terms(@params_name)
    else
      @categories = Category.with_published_products
    end


    render layout: "catalog"
  end

  def roi

    render layout: "roi"
  end


end
```

Best I can tell the original author is trying to display product_catagoires that have the status of "published".  I might be over simplfying the statement but I beleive that is what I understand it to be doing.  I know from other joins I had to fix I had to eliminate the .eq and put => in its place which I tried many versions of and it always complained about the syntax.  As an example of what I mean this was another section I fixed:

FROM:

- cds_item = item.variants.joins{vendor}.where{ vendor.code.eq 'cds' }.first

TO:

- cds_item = item.variants.joins(:vendor).where( :vendor_id => 'cds' ).first

I tried to change the line I am having the problem with to a similar format and every combination I could think of I just can't seem to speak to Rails the way it wants.

If there are any other files I need to attach please let me know.
I appreciate any input anyone has to offer.
I am willing to make the scopes less complicated and more verbose if it solves the problem I just am too new to figure this last piece out.

Thank You,
Scott

Thank You @engineersmnky,
I am now getting the following error:
Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Category#products' which goes through 'Category#product_categories' before the through association is defined.

It is referencing this line in the view:

```
- @params_name.blank? ? @products = category.products.published.includes(:pictures).order("name asc") : @products = category.products.searched(@params_name).published.includes(:pictures).order("name asc")
```

Sorry if this is not the right way to add more information, I couldn't post the line dealing with the code in a comment.

Comment: `joins{product_categories.product}` should most likely be `joins(product_categories: :product)` and `.where{products.status.eq "published"}` can be changed to `.where( products: {status: "published"})`. I honestly can't understand where the former syntax came from. That being said if it actually worked I don't hate it ;)

Comment: This one `.where{products.name.like search_terms}` is a bit more complicated. You can replace this part with `.where(Product.arel_attribute(:name).lower.matches("%#{search_terms.downcase}%"))` which should work but I am uncertain again about the prior syntax and/or how their like method was supposed to work.

Comment: Thank You @engineersmnky  I have updated the problem above I am now getting an error in the view with a REALLY LONG line which it wouldn't let me put in the comments so I had to update my problem, I couldn't seem to find a way to just ADD onto my issue?  I am still very new to stackoverflow, sorry if that was not the right way to do it.

Comment: I should also add @engineersmnky, there used to be a gem called postgres_ext that was in the gemfile but I could NOT get this gem to work with the version of Ruby and Rails I am running, it would throw a VERY long angry error.  That code DID in fact work when it was on Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.1 on Heroku on the cedar 14 stack. I couldn't find anything matching in any documentation on a lot of it.

Comment: Switch these lines `has_many :products, through: :product_categories
  has_many :product_categories, dependent: :destroy` around so that `product_categories` is defined first. Also to correct my previous comment products should be pluralized here `joins(product_categories: :products)` that being said since the association is defined it could be shortened to `joins(:products)`

Comment: Just nitpicking a bit here but `joins{product_categories.product}` is not a lambda. It's a block argument which can use `do...end` or brackets. Lambdas use the `lambda` keyword or the "stabby lambda" `->`. Lambdas can be assigned to variables and passed as positional or keyword arguments - blocks cannot and must be at the end of the arguments passed to a method.  Thus the error message `The method .joins() must contain arguments` as you're not calling it with any positional arguments.

Comment: Thank You @engineersmnky for all your help! I have the catalog working now!!. There were a few other view corrections that had to be made but that part of the APP resides outside of authentication which I didn't realize at first. I was able to figure all of those out though.  I did switch it to just :products as it is shorter and you are correct it worked the same. I can't thank you enough!  This has been the hardest project I have EVER worked on. I had no idea how hard it was to upgrade a Rails app to a new version, I have 3 other apps I will have to do this too but I learned a LOT! TY Again!

Comment: @engineersmnky if I had to venture a guess I would guess that these are [Squeel keypaths](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#keypaths) which let you write `where(foo: { bar: :baz })` as `where { foo.bar.eq("baz") }` by insane Arel trickery and monkeypatching. It also fits the narative of a Rails 4.2 legacy app as Squeel never was updated beyond that point.

Comment: Hello @max Squeel was in the gemfile and it also no longer works or at least I couldn't get it to work.  I had forgotten about that until you mentioned it.  I will have a lot of minor cleanup to do over time as some of the views still do odd things like in the catalog the categories are repeating themselves extra times even though in the database there is one 1 of each category but I'm sure that has to do with more of the same as far as the APP being written with older Ruby and Rails and now it is running on current version(s).

Comment: One acute code smell here is that there are database queries in the view. Refactor the code by moving the database queries into the controller. Your views should just take data from the controller and render it in the simplest way possible. The less logic the better when your dealing with a soup of a document structure and code. After that refactor by looking at what should be moved into the model.

Comment: Thank You @max, appreciate the feedback!  I have about a months worth of experience in Ruby/Rails so far so I have a LOT more to learn so I do appreciate ANY tips! TY!

Comment: @max thank you. I was unaware of this gem honestly. I love the syntax; however your description is terrifying so I can understand its falling out of any sort of favor

Comment: @engineersmnky Squeel had some really interesting ideas which melded Arel and ActiveRecord together in a much better DSL. I think the hackery involved in getting there was pretty problematic though and the main maintainer burned out from it breaking with every Rails release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your legacy app used a gem called [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) which monkeypatched core methods in ActiveRecord like `where`, `joins` etc to take a block argument:

```
Person.joins(:articles => {:comments => :person})
```

Becomes:

```
Person.joins{articles.comments.person}
```

The authors ambition was that Squeel would be incorporated into ActiveRecord but that didn't pass and the fact that the monkeypatches broke with every Rails release burned out the maintainers. Squeel was abandoned after Rails 4.2. But parts of it live on in the [baby_squeel gem](https://github.com/rzane/baby_squeel/blob/master/baby_squeel.gemspec).

Some of the easier cases are going to be relatively straight forward to unfurl into modern ActiveRecord code. Others like a `LIKE` query will require some Arel:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Do not use attr_accessible 
  # - model level whitelisting was replaced by strong params in Rails 4
  # attr_accessible :name

  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_categories

  # You need to declare the relations you are joining through first
  has_many :product_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :product_categories

  # default scope is evil!
  # default_scope { order("id") }

  # use `lambda do` for multi-line lambdas to keep reasonable line lengths
  # or just write regular class methods 
  scope :with_published_products, lambda do 
    joins(product_categories: :product)
      .where( products: { status: "published" } )
      .distinct
  end

  scope :with_matched_search_terms, lambda do |search_terms|
     joins(product_categories: :product)
       .where(
          Product.arel_attribute(:name)
                 .lower
                 .matches("%#{search_terms.downcase}%")
                 .distinct
       ) 
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what `#uniq` was supposed to do in the Squeel - but I believe it may have added a `distinct` clause - like `ActiveRecord::Relation#uniq` which was deprechiated in Rails 5.0.